# Allocated arrays in functions

Tags: function-pointers

Lets say you have this in main

```
int* test;
test = createArray(test);
```

and this is function

```
int * creatArray(int* temp)
{
    temp = new int [35];
    return temp
}
```

Why do you need to return the allocated space to the pointer instead of the pointer acting as if it was call by reference?  Or changing the value without returning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a call by reference, it should be declared so:

```
void creatArray(int* &temp)
{
    temp = new int [35];
}
```

Another option is to pass a pointer to your variable (which is of type "pointer to int"):

```
void creatArray(int** temp)
{
    *temp = new int [35];
}
...
createArray(&test);  // take a pointer to variable
```

Comment: Ok, that works thank you, but I still wonder, how come a pointer doesn't work without reference? Doesn't it point to what the value is?

Comment: `temp` inside createArray is a *variable* of type `int*` and has scope (lifetime) only within the function. That is, all changes to it are kept until you exit the function. To avoid this you have to pass a reference to a variable, either by & syntax or with pointer to a variable. I'll update the answer with tje second option.